# Table in Indesign not exactly a table inside text frame. What is it?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am designing a catalog using several elements from another one. BUT what looks like a table is not a table exactly. It's a text frame, it looks like it's all text frame with tabs which it's not practical at all. Is there a way of creating this in InDesign that it's not a tab? In the image below you can see what I mean. For example if I press "Enter" on Example 1, it's going to behave just like in a text frame "example 1" is going to create another line (and under "N. de Art." column).

The reason I don't use tabs is that the catalog is around 300 pages. Using tabs is not very time effective nor practical.

PS: I verified if it's columns inside the text frame, but it's not. I really hope who whoever did this file didn't used the TAB key for hundreds of tables.

[image: the "table"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose <kbd>Type</kbd> > <kbd>Show Hidden Characters</kbd> to see if tabs are used.

> [Relevant InDesign Help Article: **View hidden nonprinting characters**](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/editing-text.html#view_hidden_nonprinting_characters)

---

If it's not a table the lines propably are <kbd>Paragraph Rules</kbd>.

> [Relevant InDesign Help Article: **Add rules (lines) above or below paragraphs**](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/formatting-paragraphs.html#add_rules_lines_above_or_below_paragraphs)

Comment: That was it! Still don't know why the person thinks that this is more pratical, but anyway, it helps. thanks! =D

Comment: I mean, it was paragraph styles.

Comment: There can be advantages to using tabbed text instead of a table. For example, if you have many of these tables, tabs would allow you to change the "column" widths all at once by just changing the paragraph style. Tabbed text can also be copy/pasted in and out of InDesign much easier. I've used a text editor and regexes to clean up tab-delimited text before and then paste it into InDesign, then just apply a paragraph style, and *BOOM* I have a "table". Creating an actual table can be more manual work.

Comment: @MyNameIsHaruo: if an answer was particularly helpful, consider [marking it as Accepted](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), rather than commenting with a "thanks". As a new user, you probably want to read the introductory [tour] some time.

Comment: @Jongware I marked as Accepted. thanks for your recomendations.

Comment: @Scribblemacher I didn't thought about that it does have some advantages. But the problem is that with this client, they somethings want the text aligned to the left, sometimes to the center. So TABs might be a problem with aligment, since they don't behace the some way as tables ( I mean, they don't align with the each column)